# Best and cheapest way to host 1000s email addresses for our subscribers

Tags: email, hosting

We need to assign each subscriber to our site a unique email address that will barely be used.  What is the best way to do this?  We could host it but may be better to be hosted elsewhere.

Comment: What is the purpose of it if it will barely be used? Why would you not want to self host it?

Comment: Google Apps if you don't want to host it yourself (1000s of barely used emails will hardly make a dent in a server)

Comment: I'm assuming you've got a list of these subscribers, probably in a database.  In which case you'll be best off hosting it yourself and using a mail server which will let you store your users in a database. Postfix/Dovecot with a MySQL or LDAP database on Linux would be good, but you'd need to give more details for a detailed answer.

Comment: It is not clear what you are looking for. If I were a subscriber with an e-mail account on your server that I rarely used, it would quickly become never used.  If you want to contact me, ask me to provide an email address, then send to that.  There are a number of methods of tracing bounce messages that do not require a new email address for each user.

Answer (score 1):

The people suggesting Gmail or Google Apps aren't understanding your question/needs.

You need to explain how, specifically, the email addresses will be used even if it's not often.  Are they only used by a self-managed internal service or are they somehow accessible to the users whose subscriptions are tied to the internal addresses?

Answer (score 1):

We have a similar setup. We have nearly 30.000 accounts with a 20-30 % utilization rate. We use MDaemon. The main problem with this setup is the regular customer mailbox maintenance and customer-wide mailing operations which do a real hardware burden (mostly disk I/O). I think that we need some good customer analytics to find out who really and how uses their e-mail accounts.

Answer (score 1):

[1and1](http://www.1and1.com) has really good deals on hosting packages and email if you buy a domain.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to host it then Google Apps provides email for your own domain and such.